# Prevent layout to resize after background

Tags: android, background, android-relativelayout

Im trying to set a backgound to a RelativeLayout. 
The issue is that the layout is resized after the size of the image, which i don't want. I want the layout to be sized after the two textviews.

Anyway to prevent the layout to be scaled to the size of the background?

This is the xml-code

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/hud"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@+drawable/hud_background"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Score: " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lblScore"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblScore"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblScore"
        android:text="00" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Regards

Comment: Could you please re-word this? What do you mean by "the layout should not be sized after the image size which is happening now?"

Comment: Hope it's a bit more clear now

Comment: ouuh you mean that the relativelayout height should be textview1  height + textview2 height regardless backgroud image size..?

Comment: Well, i dont want textview1 height + textview2 height, but the height of one of the textviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is to change android:layout_width="match_parent" into android:layout_width="wrap_content" for the relativeLayout, so that the sizes will be according to the textViews alone.

Why did you add android:layout_weight="1" ? is it only a part of your layout file?

if so, if it's in a vertical linearLayout, use:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0px"
```

and if it's in a horizontal linearLayout, use:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0px"
```

Comment: Yes its a part of a vertical linear layout, and i just figured this one out as well :) thanks!